# Excel VBA "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed"

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate a form submission in Excel for work, and In have trouble with the basics. I keep getting the error message:

> "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed"

With the code as is, and if I include the Or part in the waiting check, I get the error

> "Automation Error The object invoked has disconnected from its clients."

I'm not sure what to do here, I've searched all over for solutions. This code is intended to eventually do more than this, but it keeps failing on the first try to `getElementsByTagName`.

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
Dim appIE As Object 'Internet Explorer
Set appIE = Nothing
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

If appIE Is Nothing Then Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
sURL = *link*
With appIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate sURL
End With

Do While appIE.Busy ' Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objCollection = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this same issue a while back. Use internet explorer at a medium integrity level. InternetExplorer defaults to a low integrity level which, if you are doing this over a local intranet at work, sometimes will give the second error message you show above. 
Click [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/internet-explorer-automation-protected-mode-lcie-default-integrity-level-medium.aspx) for more reading on this. I've modified your code below. Please let me know if that helps.

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
'Set appIE = Nothing
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "http://example.com"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objCollection = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Remember references for Microsoft Internet Controls, and depending on what you plan on doing further, Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, works now! (that part at least, hitting another problem after that :/ )

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly same as above code but somehow similar , the following code solved my problem:

```
Do
Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
Do
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
```

Just put it before the line you want to start working with the contents.
To get more information about how does it work you can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534361(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The below method solved my problem for this error:
Close all the explorer instances through 'Task manager' and try to run the code it will work.