# VBA Auto Login Web page and fetch the data

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to login Web page and fetch data however my  login details are not getting update, i have tried all possibilities code from your forum, nothing is working for me

Below is my code, am getting attached error

[image: Error Screen Shot]

```
Sub test()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://portal.expeditors.com/expo/login"

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    'Get all the elements with input tag name
    Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    i = 0
    'Loop through all elements and find login form and fill it
    While i < objCollection.Length
        'Login name
        If objCollection(i).Name = "username" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = "bom-sumand"
        End If

        'Store login button in object
        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    'Click login
    objElement.Click
    'Clean up
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What references have you checked ?

Comment: Hello imran, thanks for the reply, not understood your question? can you please explain

Comment: I am not getting any error message while executing your code, please make sure you have added Internet controls reference in VBA editor TOOLS==> References==>Microsoft Internet Controls and try.

Comment: Try using Internet Explorer Medium if this continues. Might be GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}") - you will need to check

Comment: Hello Arun, "Microsoft Internet Controls" already been added in References

Comment: Please verify same question      <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086425/excel-vba-method-document-of-object-iwebbrowser2-failed>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Macro trying and failing to open a second instance of IE try this.

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As Object
Dim redURL As String
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim i As Integer

redURL = "https://portal.expeditors.com/expo/login"
On Error Resume Next
Set ie = GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")
If Err Then
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate redURL

Do While ie.Busy
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Arun, thank you, am able to navigate web page however unable to update my login details

Answer (score 1):

I would use the available ids rather than looping to find the input boxes and sign in. These are much faster selector methods. You can add a  .Focus. Also, swop InternetExplorer for InternetExplorerMeduim in some cases.

If problem continues check your internet settings in case site is blocked.

Open the URL via creating an IE instance direct.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Login()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer               'InternetExplorerMedium
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Dim t As Date, ele As Object
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://portal.expeditors.com/expo/login"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .getElementById("j_username")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing

            If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

            With ele
                .Focus
                .Value = "bob"
            End With
            With .getElementById("j_password")
                .Focus
                .Value = "penny"
            End With

            .getElementById("signInBtn").Click

        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting error in this code  "While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend" and Error is Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005); Automation error Unspecified error

Comment: Try running again and use  Dim ie As New  InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: Added "Dim ie As New InternetExplorerMedium " still same issue " Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005); Automation error Unspecified"

Comment: Is the site blacklisted by your security settings?

Comment: yes, you are right,  Automatically detect settings was disable in internet explore, now its working perfectly fine, thank you very much for great support

Comment: Ok, Message Noted

Comment: trying to navigate further getting run time error object required    ie.navigate "https://expo.expeditors.com/expotr/expotr?action=com.expd.webapp.tracking.action.searches.SearchWebAction&SearchType=advancedshipment.BaseAdvancedShipmentSearch&reference=4220340930"

Comment: I don't think the error would be on that line. Which line is the error actually on?

Comment: With .getElementById("j_username")
                .focus
                .Value = "bob"
            End With

Comment: try the edited version  and let me know. There is a timed loop which you can increase from 5 seconds to wait for element to be present.

Comment: yes, problem solved, further need to download all the documents linked under this references, URL  "https://expo.expeditors.com/expotr/expotr?action=com.expd.webapp.tracking.action.document.DocumentImageDownloadWebAction&Type=Image.Get&xref=utbY7EWF98bNjBJgJX0qGubmHC8KZv9cJLDToqpU3UOz8RpExFamOA%3D%3D"

Comment: Please ask a new question and happy to help. Bear in mind if login based you will need to share the whole html of the page most likely. https://pastebin.com/ is good for that.

Comment: Did you unaccept on that basis? What is missing please from the above?

Comment: You said the problem was internet settings and needing a wait.... how does the other answer address either of those or inputting your info?

Comment: As you mentioned that i should ask a new question hence i have posted a new question for this query, hope my understanding is correct?

Comment: yes, after internet setting, i am able to login web page via VBA excel, however i need to further develop this script hence i have posted new question